Sequelize returning true is not working after updating v6 for mysql
I am using sequelize js v6 for MySQL Database. I want to get an updated result when I update the database but it only returns [ undefined, 1 ]
I also read their documentation but they say returning is no longer so which one will support they did not clearly mention.
Here is the link: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/upgrade/#optionsreturning
app.get("/global", async (req, res, next) => {

    const update = await Model.update({ total: 11 }, { where: { id: 172 }, plain: true, 
    returning: true })

    console.log(update)

    res.json({ success: true, data: update })

})


 


What about returning: ['*']?

Thanks for your comment. It does not work. I also tried it that time.

Could you add the generated SQL for returning: true case?

The returning option is not supported for MySQL, only Postgres. (See description for options.returning in the Sequelize API docs).
If you're only updating a single record, you're better off getting a model instance and updating it:
app.get("/global", async (req, res, next) => {

    const modelInstance = await Model.findOne({ where: { id: 172 } });
    modelInstance.set({ total: 11 });
    await modelInstance.save();
    console.log(modelInstance.toJSON());
    
    res.json({ success: true, data: modelInstance })
});

If you're updating multiple rows, the only way I know of to return the updated rows definitively is to use a list of ids:
app.get("/global", async (req, res, next) => {

    const idObjects = await Model.findMany({
        where: { /* your criteria here */ },
        attributes: ['id'], // we'll only need the ids at first
        raw: true, // tells sequelize to just return plain objects, since we don't need model instances
    });
    const idsToUpdate = idObjects.map(o => o.id);
    const [countUpdated] = await Model.update({ total: 11 }, {
        where: {
            id: idsToUpdate,
        },
    });
    console.log(`Updated ${countUpdated} records`);

    const updatedRecords = await Model.findMany({
        where: {
            id: idsToUpdate,
        },
    });
    
    res.json({ success: true, data: updatedRecords })
});

